# RBAC in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, roles, minikube, rbac, k8s-rolebinding

I am practicing RBAC in Kubernetes on Minikube. I have created a user with an approved certificate. Now, I want to practice roles and role bindings with that user. However, when I try to access Minikube's pods using that user, I encounter the following error.

- error: tls: failed to find "CERTIFICATE" PEM block in certificate input after skipping PEM blocks of the following types: [CERTIFICATE REQUEST]

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to answer your question. It looks like you've created credentials using a certificate request rather than a certificate. Can you update your question to include the complete set of steps you performed to create and obtain the user certificate?